# Counting consecutive rows based off of a calculation

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to calculate the number of consecutive hours a transformer is overloaded. The transformer can be determined as overloaded by dividing the usage by the size and multiplying it by 100 to get the percentage. The overload lookup table contains the parameters for calculating. This needs to be done dynamically, this is why I am not hard coding it into a query, in the case that I need to add more parameters or change the current parameters. If a transformer is overloaded by 150-174.99 percent for four hours or more, it would be considered as overloaded. If a transformer is overloaded by 175-199.99 percent for two or more hours it would be considered as overloaded and if a transformer is overloaded by 200 percent or more for a single hour or more than it would also be considered as overloaded. **Result Set 1** has almost the desired output. Notice the caveat on row three. The same query was used to calculate **Result Set 2** The results set is correct if the query is run for just that day and for that transformer. When I removed the where clause on transformer and date the calculations go wonky. I need this to be able to be run on a large number or results so limiting the results or creating a function will not work. The output is all wrong.

Eventually I need to take this data and show that transformer# was was overloaded [n] number of times in a single day for [n] number of hours. **Result Set 1** needs to show that transformer 318 was overloaded 1 time for 7 hours. If another overload sequence was to occur starting at hour 12 and continue for four hours then the aggregated results should show that the transformer was overloaded 2 times for a total of 11 hours. When I drill down into this data from a report then I want to see what the result sets are below.

**Query**

```
DROP TABLE #TransformerLoading;
DROP TABLE #OverloadLookup;

CREATE TABLE #TransformerLoading(
TransformerID int,
[Date] date,
Size int,
Usage decimal,
[Hour] int,
OverloadPercent decimal
);
INSERT INTO #TransformerLoading
VALUES
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   7.3728, 1,          147.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   8.2944, 2,          166.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   7.3728, 3,          147.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   7.9872, 4,          160.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   8.6016, 5,          172.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   7.9872, 6,          160.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   9.6000, 7,          192.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   7.9872, 8,          160.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   8.4480, 9,          169.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   7.5264, 10,         151.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   7.0656, 11,         141.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   7.8336, 12,         157.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   6.6048, 13,         132.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   6.2976, 14,         126.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   6.6048, 15,         132.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   6.6048, 16,         132.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   6.4512, 17,         129.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   5.5296, 18,         111.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   5.0688, 19,         101.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   5.2224, 20,         104.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   6.1440, 21,         123.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   6.2976, 22,         126.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   3.6864, 23,         74.00),
     (318,  '2019-01-11',   5.00,   3.6864, 24,         74.00),
     (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   146.7000,    1,       978.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   147.1500,    2,       981.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   146.7000,    3,       978.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   147.6000,    4,       984.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   146.7000,    5,       978.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   147.6000,    6,       984.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   147.6000,    7,       984.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   147.6000,    8,       984.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   147.6000,    9,       984.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   147.1500,    10,      981.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   145.8000,    11,      972.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   144.9000,    12,      966.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   145.8000,    13,      972.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   145.3500,    14,      969.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   144.9000,    15,      966.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   126.9000,    16,      846.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   114.7500,    17,      765.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   114.3000,    18,      762.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   115.2000,    19,      768.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   112.9500,    20,      753.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   112.5000,    21,      750.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   112.9500,    22,      753.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   112.9500,    23,      753.00),
 (3403,   '2019-01-11',  15.00,   112.9500,    24,      753.00)
 ;

 CREATE TABLE #OverloadLookup(
 [Hours] int,
 MinPercent decimal,
 MaxPercent decimal
 );

 insert into #OverloadLookup
 VALUES
 (4,150,174.99),
 (2,175,199.99),
 (1,200,99999.99)
 ;

with  a as (
    select *
           ,row_number() OVER (Order by date, [hour]) RowNumber,
           case when [hours] is null then 0 else 1 end IsOverloaded,
           row_number() over (partition by transformerid, date, case when [hours] is null then 0 else 1 end order by date, [hour]) PartitionedRowNumber,
           GroupByRowNumber = row_number() OVER (Order by date, [hour]) - row_number() over (partition by transformerid, date, case when [hours] is null then 0 else 1 end order by date, [hour])
    from #TransformerLoading tl
           left join #OverloadLookup ol on tl.OverloadPercent between ol.MinPercent and ol.MaxPercent
    where tl.Date = '1/11/2019' --and tl.TransformerID = 3403
)
select TransformerID, date, size, usage, hour, OverloadPercent, [Hours], MinPercent, MaxPercent, IsOverloaded,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by GroupByRowNumber ORDER BY GroupBYROWNUMBER, [Hour]) ConsecutiveCount
FROM a
order by TransformerID, Date, Hour
```

**OverloadLookup**

```
 Hours   MinPercent     MaxPercent
   4        150           174.99
   2        175           199.99
   1        200         99999.99
```

**Result Set 1**

```
 TransformerID  date    size    usage   hour    OverloadPercent Hours   MinPercent  MaxPercent  IsOverloaded    ConsecutiveCount
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    7.3728  1           147.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 1
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    8.2944  2           166.00        4       150         174.99          1                 1
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    7.3728  3           147.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 2 (This needs to be one)
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    7.9872  4           160.00        4       150         174.99          1                 1
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    8.6016  5           172.00        4       150         174.99          1                 2
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    7.9872  6           160.00        4       150         174.99          1                 3
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    9.6000  7           192.00        2       175         199.99          1                 4
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    7.9872  8           160.00        4       150         174.99          1                 5
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    8.4480  9           169.00        4       150         174.99          1                 6
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    7.5264  10          151.00        4       150         174.99          1                 7
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    7.0656  11          141.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 1
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    7.8336  12          157.00        4       150         174.99          1                 1
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    6.6048  13          132.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 1
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    6.2976  14          126.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 2
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    6.6048  15          132.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 3
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    6.6048  16          132.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 4
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    6.4512  17          129.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 5
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    5.5296  18          111.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 6
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    5.0688  19          101.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 7
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    5.2224  20          104.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 8
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    6.1440  21          123.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 9
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    6.2976  22          126.00       NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 10
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    3.6864  23          74.00        NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 11
     318    2019-01-11  5.00    3.6864  24          74.00        NULL    NULL          NULL           0                 12
```

**Result Set 2**

```
 TransformerID  date    size    usage      hour OverloadPercent Hours   MinPercent  MaxPercent  IsOverloaded    ConsecutiveCount         
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   146.7000    1       978.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   147.1500    2       981.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1 (This needs to be two)
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   146.7000    3       978.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1 (This needs to be three)
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   147.6000    4       984.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1 (ect...)
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   146.7000    5       978.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 3
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   147.6000    6       984.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   147.6000    7       984.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 3
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   147.6000    8       984.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   147.6000    9       984.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 3
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   147.1500    10      981.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   145.8000    11      972.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 2   
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   144.9000    12      966.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 2
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   145.8000    13      972.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   145.3500    14      969.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 2
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   144.9000    15      966.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1       
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   126.9000    16      846.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 2
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   114.7500    17      765.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   114.3000    18      762.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 2
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   115.2000    19      768.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   112.9500    20      753.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 2
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   112.5000    21      750.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   112.9500    22      753.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 2
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   112.9500    23      753.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 1
     3403   2019-01-11  15.00   112.9500    24      753.00        1        200      9999999.00        1                 2
```

Comment: Please read the first two paragraphs in the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by TransformerID, [Date] ORDER BY TransformerID, [Date]) 'Hour'` ?  Seems to me that can only return 1? Maybe that should be  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TransformerID, CAST([Date] AS DATE) ORDER BY [Date]) AS [Hour]`

Comment: So 170% for 3 hours followed by 190% for 1 hour allows it to cool enough to avoid an overload? Tips: Providing DDL and consumable sample data help us help you. It's also helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: i have edited the query so that you can run it and return the results that I have. Im sorry for the confusion